# Changing static URL as Dynamic - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express

I have a directory where all the songs uploaded by user get uploaded. I have used mongodb for this app, mongodb is working fine but I want to use 
src url like uploads/something to songs/user/songname I have tried to used Router.get as shown in the Controller.js
But when I use this I have got the internal 500 error, Please let me knwo where I had made mistake.

**controller.js**

```
Router.get('/songs/:artist/:song', (req, response) => {
    console.dir(req.query)
    let file = './uploads/01-Whole Lotta Love.mp3'
    var stat = FileSystem.statSync(file)

    response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'audio/mpeg');
    response.setHeader('Content-Length', stat.length);

    fs.createReadStream(file).pipe(response);
})
```

**app.js**

```
app.use(Express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'uploads')));
```

**profile.ejs**

```
<table border="1">
    <% artist.songs.forEach((song) => { %>
    <tr>
        <td> <%= song.song %> </td>
        <td>
            <audio controls>
                <source src="./songs/<%= artist.artistName+ '/' + song.audioPath %>" type="audio/mpeg">
                Your browser does not support the audio element.
            </audio>
        </td>
        <td>3k listens</td>
        <td>2k likes</td>
        <td>2k comments</td>
    </tr>
    <% }) %>
</table>
```

its like what ever I write for **songs/anyusername/songname** will use the directory **uploads/songname**

thankyou in advance :)

Comment: Unless it's a server/express config/syntax error, maybe using the HTML base tag might help in your case: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

Comment: Why don't you show what the generated HTML file looks like (what the browser sees), not the template.  You can get that with View/Source in the browser.   Probably your song URLs are wrong in the HTML page, but you need to see the generate HTML to know for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code, open in browser: `http://host:port/song/foo/bar` 
and write in comment what You get:

```
const 
  fs = require('fs'),
  path = require('path'),
  bufferSize = 100 * 1024;

Router.get('/songs/:artist/:song', (req, res) => {
  let 
    file = '01-Whole Lotta Love.mp3';
    file = path.join(__dirname, 'uploads', file);

  console.log('Piping file:', file); // check if path is correct

  fs.stat(file, 
    (err, stat) => { 
      if(err) {
        return res.status(500).send(err); // output error to client
      }

      res.writeHead(200, {
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate',
        'Pragma': 'no-cache',
        'Expires': 0,
        'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg',
        'Content-Length': stat.size
      });
      fs.createReadStream(file, {bufferSize}).pipe(res);
  });
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much @num8er I made some url edits on your code and now it start to work as a charm \m/